# How to match features to xgboost feature importance

Tags: pandas, xgboost, feature-selection

I have used xgboost feature importance to get feature importance scores using the floowing code:

```
from xgboost import XGBRegressor
from xgboost import plot_importance
from matplotlib import pyplot

model = XGBRegressor()
model.fit(X_train2, y_train)
# plot feature importance
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 15))
plot_importance(model)
pyplot.show()
```

I have both ordinal encoded and onehotencoded variables so my question is how can i match the f scores to the correct feature names

Comment: _How_ have you ordinal and one-hot encoded the variables? Is `X_train` a dataframe, a numpy array, a scipy sparse array, ...?